# Scattering state solution for delta well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, scattering

For delta well $V(x) = -a \delta(x)$ we have the solution for TISE as $$\psi_1(x) = A e^{ikx} + B e^{-ikx}$$ for $x<0$ and $$\psi_2(x) = F e^{ikx} + G e^{-ikx}$$ for $x>0$

where $k>0$

after adding the time dependent term,it's the travelling wave solution.

When we consider the wave scattering from left,we will set $G =0$ what I don't understand is why don't set $B = 0$.
In the Griffiths quantum mechanics textbook page 74 it says $B$ is the reflection of the wave,but why it must be the reflection not the wave from right?Since by symmetry,B can be the transmission of wave from right.

And in the same page,the wave correspond to A is called incident wave ,B reflected wave and F transmitted wave,the terminology is weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *is* no wave from the right.  You're performing the analysis under the assumption that a wave is incident on the barrier *from the left*; as a result, there will be an incident component on the left $(A)$, a reflected component on the left $(B)$, and a transmitted component on the right $(F)$.

Comment: Do you mean any reasonable A, B, F, G is allowed,here we set a specific solution for the equation to see what will happen?

Comment: @yi_li In this particular case, you are assuming a wave incident from the left, which means that there is no wave traveling to the left on the right side of the barrier, meaning that $G=0$.  In principle you could have waves coming from both sides.